# Can Anyone Identify This Bug

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I am looking for someone to identify this bug:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to have a closer image, but at first glance, it looks like some sort of weevil

Comment: Can you tell us where you found the insect?

Comment: This is definitely some species of grain weevil. If you can provide more about it's size, location, where you found it (e.g., what type of food), and whether or not you've seen it fly, then someone should be able to give you an exact ID.

Answer (score 3):

It is an [ormányosbogár](http://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orm%C3%A1nyosbog%C3%A1r-f%C3%A9l%C3%A9k) species. :D
[Curculionidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curculionidae) in Latin. I don't know the exact species, but it is common here in Hungary.

It is something like Mecinus janthinus, but it seems like shorter. Probably [Mecinus pyraster](https://www.flickr.com/photos/micks-wildlife-macros/4041408914/in/pool-britishbeetles|micks-wildlife-macros) or another [Mecinus species](http://claude.schott.free.fr/Mecininae/Mecininae_PL1.jpg).

[image: Mecinus janthinus]

- Figure 1 - Mecinus janthinus - [source](http://www.nhmus.hu/~podlussany/ormanyosfotok.html)

I think it is [Sitophilus granarius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_weevil) aka. wheat weevil, but it is hard to decide because of the poor quality photo...

[image: Sitophilus granarius]

- Figure 2 - Sitophilus granarius - wheat weevil - [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_weevil)

Comment: The second one looks better, it fits the ratio of the original image better, your first image has a thorax that looks too short.

Comment: @user137 Yepp, I think too that it is the second one.

Comment: Note that Curculionidae is a very species-rich family though (e.g. 780 species in Germany, >500 in Sweden, ~60000 known worldwide). Without size, location and a better picture I don't think this can be determined to species.

Comment: @fileunderwater I agree, better photo needed, or DNA sample :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely Sitophilus granarius [wheat weevil].It is a common pest in India, as it mostly attacks wheat grains stored in sacks.When we buy plain grains of wheat from shops we can see these pests inside and there may be plenty of them drilling the wheat and leave the empty crest of wheat behind.

Comment: You should provide evidence with your answer - it's part of writing a good answer, see the help pages.